# Round a float up to the next integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding

I need to round floating point numbers up to the nearest integer, even if the number after the point is less than 0.5.

For example,

- 4.3 should be 5 (not 4)
- 4.8 should be 5

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use the [`Math.ceil`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) function

```
var n = 4.3;
alert(Math.ceil(n)); //alerts 5
```

Answer (score 19):

Use `ceil`

```
var n = 4.3;
n = Math.ceil(n);// n is 5
```

Comment: I removed my comment, you are right. I did not see you rewriting var n. I have submitted an edit

Answer (score 16):

Round up to the second (0.00) decimal point:

```
 var n = 35.85001;
 Math.ceil(n * 100) / 100;  // 35.86
```

to first (0.0):

```
 var n = 35.800001;
 Math.ceil(n * 10) / 10;    // 35.9
```

to integer:

```
 var n = 35.00001;
 Math.ceil(n);              // 36
```

[`jsbin.com`](http://jsbin.com/kolejusizi/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
Math.ceil( floatvalue );
```

It will round the value as desired.