# how can i change decimal number to integer using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change decimal value  to integer have tried multiple way but can't get it.

example

i have tried this and it work in most of my cases

```
     n = 1.75 // value to 2 which i can do using
var num = 1.75;           
var n = num.toFixed()
```

; // prints 2  but to change
i have used to fixed function which give me answer in this condition

but it fail to give me the desired output here how to get in these condition
with any other solution

```
n = 1.25 // value to 2
```

i don't know how to perform this.

Comment: `Math.ceil(n)` will give the result [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Comment: Math.ceil(1.75), should do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round a float up to the next integer in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187367/round-a-float-up-to-the-next-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(1.2));
console.log(Math.ceil(1.7));
```

Think of `ceil()` as for ceiling, meaning the upper closes integer value

Comment: Mark it as a duplicate